# Bootstrap carousel doesn't work after I remove the active class

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I made a page and I get from database an array of paths

eg:

```
 images/file_name.jpg
```

and I want to display those images in a carousel from bootstrap

```
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                  <% for(let picture of modelpics) { %>

                                  <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="/<%= picture %>" >
                                  </div>
                                  <% }%>
                                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                </a>
                                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                </a>
                              </div>
                        </div>
```

Data are fetched correctly from db. I'm working with EJS, NodeJS and Mongoose. Can you please tell me what should I do for this to work? I copied the code from Boostrap Page , but it's not working, I also deleted that active class, maybe that's why, but how can I programatically add new "Carousel Item " after that active class? If I do ' picture[0] ' it wont work in that " FOR ".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

running in same issue, using node js, ejs and mysql. Getting individual arrays of paths representing images to show in a bs carousel.

Therefore you need the item-active and item class respectively two image, src classes. To differentiate while looping put in an "if - else" clause running a var like i==0 -> active class, else -> other items for indexing array inputs.

Hope this is a start.

Answer (score 0):

works for me:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <% for (var pfad of players){%>
    <% if (i==0) {%>  
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <%} else {%>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<% i %>"></li>
    <!--<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>-->
    <% } %>
    <% i = i+1; %>
    <% } %>
  </ol>

  <!--<ol class="carousel-indicators">-->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% var i = 0; %>
    <% for(var pfad of players){%> 
    <% if (i==0) {%>
    <!--<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>--> 
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="<%= '/assets/img/' + pfad.image_gallery %>" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <%} else {%>
      <!--<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<% i %>"></li>-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<%= '/assets/img/' + pfad.image_gallery %>" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
    <% } %>
    <% i = i+1; %>
    <% } %>
  </div>
  <!--</ol>-->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```